# Where can I find a clear cut documentation/tutorial on installing and using pymssql and FreeTDS?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've tried searching and installing many guides on google but all my attempts come back with some sort of error. I'm feeling frustrated and thought I'd ask if anyone here knows how to get pymssql and FreeTDS to install and run properly together or Atleast point me in a better direction than I've been going.

Edit: I'm trying to do this on Windows 10.

Comment: what platform are you on?

Comment: Windows 10, sorry should have mentioned that.

Comment: There aren't any native libraries to build pymssql against?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, and I wouldn't know where to begin with it.

Comment: "tried searching and installing many guides on google but all my attempts come back with some sort of error", maybe you can re-post your question with the issues/errors you are facing, this way we can help you?